# I have two Preseed files, one is "corrupted" and other is fine

Tags: preseed

I have a working preseed file that I cobbled to together manually. Ubuntu 14.04.1 likes this file and will installed in a completely unattended manner. I then took and wrote some C# to write out preseed files based on given parameters. Ubuntu 14.04.1 does NOT like this file. The install always errors with "Syntax Error: unable to determine template type". This happens during the recipe, after the definition of the boot volume.

Here are both files: http://www.filedropper.com/ubuntu-14cfg

I've been banging my head against this for 2 solid days now and do NOT see a difference between the two. Does anyone else see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to run `diff` on the two files? Almost all lines differ in white-space amounts. With `diff -uw` I still get some differences that appear to be white-space only despite the `-w` option. Additionally `file` tells me, that those files have carriage return characters at the end of their lines, which many *nix tools don't like.

Comment: I've tried both with just LF and CR and CRLF, no change. I'd bite on the whitespace thing, but not every line seems to care as there is no consistent whitespace usage.

Comment: I don't know what the difference in the partman section was, but after changing up how I defined the partman section in C# from a single-line string with \\\r\n to a literal multi-line string the preseed file was able to be processed successfully.

Comment: Ah, there it is. The first "Auto" file used "\ " in the recipe section. Changing this to "\" resolved my issue.

Comment: Can you please write an answer with your solution to your own question? Ping me in this comment section, so I can vote for it, if it's [a good answer](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the line continuation characters ("\") had a space after them ("\ ") in the recipe section of my preseed file. This, apparently breaks ALL of the parsers in preseed. Using "\ " in the late_command also results in a failure to parse.